# Terminology: 'Definite' or 'Indefinite' integral? Wiki vs Visual Calculus

Tags: integration, terminology

Visual Calculus
http://archives.math.utk.edu/visual.calculus/4/ftc.9/
states
$$A(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt $$
 is "an indefinite integral or antiderivative of f".

Whereas https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative
says 
$$F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt $$
is "the definite integral of f with variable upper boundary".

*Which is correct?*

Comment: I'd say they're both correct. A definite integral with a fixed lower boundary and variable upper boundary is a function of the upper boundary whose derivative is the integrand (assuming, say, continuity of the integrand). So it is an antiderivative of the integrand. If you fix a different lower boundary, you get (in general) a different antiderivative, differing from the first antiderivative by a constant.

Comment: Usually the indefinite integral is defined as just the antiderivative and its notation does not show any bounds at all: $\int f(x) dx$. In Visual Calculus's case, they added bounds to make clear what the variable of the function is, and what the variable of integration is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct. Using the definite integral with a constant lower limit and the variable as the upper limit results in one particular indefinite integral/antiderivative.